# Sensitivity Analysis: Calculating Allowable increase/Decrease for a Binding Constraint

Tags: analysis, optimization

Let say we have the following equations:

Objective Function = $7T+5C$

Contraints
$3T + 4C \le 2400$
$2T + C \le 1000$
$C \le 450$
$T\le 100$

How would we calculate the allowable increase and decrease for the first constraint in a sensitivity analysis?

Comment: Use the graphical method

Comment: Is it possible to use the equations without graphing?

Comment: yeah you can use simplex method if you know that, but i suggest to use graphical method for two variables. note that maxima or minima exits at corner points so you need to find corner points of the graph.

Comment: $\texttt{Hint: }$ You need the $\color{blue}{\text{optimal tableau}}$ to make a sensivity analysis.